# Smooth horizontal scrolling text

Tags: android, scroll

I understand that this might be a duplicate, but I havent found an answer.....yet!

How can I make a **smooth** horizontal scrolling text in my Android-app? I want the text to scroll like a stockticker on the TV-news. I also need a callback when the scrolling is completed so i can  set a new text to scroll.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any kind of design..then update with that what kind of scrolling you actually need

Answer (score 0):

For Manually Scrolling

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="Horizontal scroll view is working"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

For Automatic Scrolling

```
<TextView
    android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit " 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: I think he wants it to scroll automatically.

Comment: Yes, I wants it to scroll automatically.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I get a notification when the scrolling is completed?

Comment: as scrolling is completed it stops for a while and it starts again.it will scroll forever

Comment: Yes I understands that, but when it stops I want to replace the text with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question.

First of all to do this, place following code in your `layout` file for `TextView`

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:focusable="false"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Then write following code in your code file,

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
txt.setSelected(true);
```

You must give `setSelected(true)` to make textview scroll automatically.

Thanks.